# Help to draw graphs in tkz-graph package

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-graph

I would like to draw the following graphs in tkz-graph package. These are the unit-distance colored Golomb graph and Moser spindle respectively.

[image]

[image]

when i try using the regular polygon operation it misaligns the edges and the second graph isnt regular so idk how to draw it

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: when i try using the regular polygon operation it misaligns the edges and the second graph isnt regular so idk how to draw it

Comment: If the green vertex is at the origin, what would be the polar coordinates of the blue vertex in the inside triangle? (actually, I just need the angle)

Comment: @rvf0068 I think that you only need the information that all edges are of equal length. I am not 100% sure about this, but looking at the diagrams, I think this is actually the key to the placement of the nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one, you can stack two `\Vertices` commands. But some calculations are necessary if all edges shall have the same length:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\u}{3}
    \Vertices[unit=3]{circle}{A,B,C,D,E,F}

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\v}{\u*sqrt(3)/3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{acos((\u*\u-\u*\u-\v*\v)/(-2*\v*\u))-120}    
    \begin{scope}[rotate={\r}]
        \Vertices[unit={\v}]{circle}{G,H,I}
    \end{scope}
    \Vertex{K}

    \AddVertexColor{red}{B,E,I} 
    \AddVertexColor{blue}{A,D,G}
    \AddVertexColor{white}{C,F,H}
    \AddVertexColor{green}{K}
    
    \Edges(A,B,C,D,E,F,A)
    \Edges(G,H,I,G)
    \Edges(A,H)
    \Edges(C,I)
    \Edges(E,G)
    \Edges(A,K,D)
    \Edges(B,K,E)
    \Edges(C,K,F)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

For the second, some calculations are necessary as well:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\u}{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{acos((\u*sin(60))/(6*\u*sin(30)))}

    \begin{scope}[rotate={\r-60}]
        \Vertices[unit=\u]{circle}{A,B,C}
    \end{scope}
    \coordinate (X) at ($(A)!(C)!(B)$);
    \coordinate (D) at ($(C)!2!(X)$);
    \Vertex[Node]{D}

    \begin{scope}[xshift={2*\u*cos(\r)*2cm}, rotate={120-\r}]
        \Vertices[unit=\u]{circle}{E,F,G}
    \end{scope}

    \AddVertexColor{red}{B,G} 
    \AddVertexColor{blue}{F} 
    \AddVertexColor{green}{A,E} 
    \AddVertexColor{yellow}{C,D} 

    \Edges(A,B,C,A)
    \Edges(E,F,G,E)
    \Edges(A,D,B)
    \Edges(E,D,F)
    \Edges(C,G)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for my multiple edits. I only later saw that the edges did not have the same length in my original version of the code.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution using the `graphs` libraries.

For the first diagram, all but the green node are placed in a cicular arrangement (specified by the `counterclockwise` key). The radius for the inner set of nodes is calculated so that the edge between them is as long as the radius of the outer set (which is also the distance between them).
The phase for the inner set is calculated from the isosceles triangle between the middle green node, the inner blue one and the outer red one in the bottom right quadrant. It comes out to 43.2213451° (although PGFMath only calculates it to be 32.2222°.)

For the second diagram, the `graphs` library is used without any circular placement rule.
In fact, all nodes are placed manually. The function `a` specifies the length of an edge and all placements are dependent on them.

The first nodes placed are the two bottom ones, all others are calculated. It's basically all trigonometry again because you always have isosceles triangles and the other angles can be calculated.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, graphs.standard}
\tikzset{color or style/.code 2 args={\tikzset{#1 #2/.try}\ifpgfkeyssuccess\else\tikzset{#1=#2}\fi}}
\tikzset{
  my graphs/.style={
    thick,
    fill  blue/.style={fill={rgb,255:red, 0;green,129;blue,255}},
    fill green/.style={fill={rgb,255:red,26;green,193;blue, 26}},
    circ/.style={shape=circle, draw},
    graphs/every graph/.append style={
      nodes={circ, color or style={fill}{\tikzgraphnodetext}},
      fresh nodes, empty nodes}}}
\begin{document}
\tikz[my graphs]\graph {
  subgraph C_n[
    name=outer,
    V={blue, red, white, blue, red, white},
    radius=1.5cm,
    counterclockwise
  ] -- green,
} graph {
  subgraph C_n[
    name=inner, V={blue, white, red},
    phase=asin(.5*sqrt(11/3))-30, radius=1.5cm/sqrt 3, counterclockwise
  ],
  (outer blue) -- (inner white),
  (outer white) -- (inner red),
  (outer red') -- (inner blue)
};

\tikz[my graphs, declare function={a=2;}]
  \graph[no placement]{
    yellow[x=-a/2] -- red[x=a/2],
    yellow[y=sqrt 11*a/2],
    red  [at={($(yellow)+({ 30+acos(.5/sqrt 3)}:a)$)}],
    green[at={($(yellow)+({-30+acos(.5/sqrt 3)}:a)$)}],
    blue [at={($(red)+({180+30-acos(.5/sqrt 3)}:a)$)}],
    green[at={($(red)+({180-30-acos(.5/sqrt 3)}:a)$)}],
    % alternative for the four previous lines above:
%    \foreach[count=\b from 0] \st/\l in {yellow/{red, green}, red/{blue, green}} {
%      \foreach{{[count=\a from 0] \L}}in \l {
%        \L[at={($(\st)+({180*\b+30*(\a?-1:1)+(\b?-1:1)*acos(.5/sqrt 3)}:a)$)}]}},
       (yellow) -- (red') -- (yellow') -- (green') -- (blue)
    -- (yellow') -- (green) -- {(red'), (yellow)},
    (red) -- {(green'), (blue)}
  };
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: I also wondered whether they are equidistant. You don't really set this explicitly, right? But maybe the library already takes care of this. They do look right (I made sure that the edges are equidistant in my solution and the results look pretty much exactly like yours).

Comment: @JasperHabicht No, I don't. I didn't realize at first that they should be equidistant and just chose 45° for the phase. [But that seems incorrect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhuUu.png) [It appears it is rather 43°.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fsLN.png). Doing the math, it should be `asin(.5*sqrt(11/3))-30°` or 43.2213451°. I've adjusted the answer accordingly.